# assigning value to a select box

Tags: jquery

Hello i have a variable in jquery with the string "tuesday" in it, i also have a selectbox with all the days of the week in it, how can i assign my variable so that the selectbox automaticly selects my variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [*val()*](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
​$('select').val("Tuesday");​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Example:  **http://jsfiddle.net/EWVct/**

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourselectvalue = 'tuesday';    
var selectobject=document.getElementById("yourselectboxid")

for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
        if (selectobject.options[i].value == yourselectvalue) {
            selectobject.options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
```